# Selecting all checkboxes with values present in an array

Tags: jquery

I have a group of checkboxes in a div. Here is one as an example:

```
<input id="customer426693" name="customers" type="checkbox" class="filled-in form-check-input customerCheckbox customerRequired" value="426693">
```

I have also in my javascript function an array of values to be selected. Is there an elegant way to select all checkboxes that have values that exist in the array using jquery?

Thanks.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: "That have values" you mean checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```js
var selectedList = [3,4,6];

function MakeSelected() {

    $("#checkBoxContainer").find("input").each(function(index,item){
    
        if(selectedList.indexOf( $(item).data("customerid") )>=0)
          $(item).prop("checked",true);
          
    });
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
I deleted class to make more readable.
</p>

<div id="checkBoxContainer">

   <input id="customer1" type="checkbox" value="1" data-customerid="1" />1 <br>
   <input id="customer2" type="checkbox" value="2" data-customerid="2" />2 <br>
   <input id="customer3" type="checkbox" value="3" data-customerid="3" />3 <br>
   <input id="customer4" type="checkbox" value="4" data-customerid="4" />4 <br>
   <input id="customer5" type="checkbox" value="5" data-customerid="5" />5 <br>
   <input id="customer6" type="checkbox" value="6" data-customerid="6" />6 <br>

</div>

<button type="button" onclick="MakeSelected()">try it!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is nice.